# How do you round a time and date back to a previous day with a formula in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, time, date

I am trying to sum up hours for an employee worked in one shift.  The employees I'm having a problem with are on night shift.  The employees entries in excel are shown as individual tickets for work done. Let's say the employee starts a ticket at 11:00pm and ends it at 2:30am, then the next ticket starts at 2:30am and ends at 5:00am.  I need those 2 tickets to show entered hours for the date of the first ticket of the shift rather than the next day.  I need some form of formula that could work across multiple employees for a month of work on 2 different shifts: Day 5:45am to 6:00pm and Night 5:45pm to 6:00am.

My columns are:

- A) Ticket Number
- B) Employee Name
- C) Total Ticket Hours [4.5]
- D) Start Time [4/5/2018 22:00]
- E) End Time [4/6/2018 2:30]

I am using Office 365 Excel 2016

Comment: just subtract D from E and format the result as time.  This works if the date/time are true date/time and not strings that work like date time.  Also they need to include the date not just the time.

Comment: Are times stored as Excel date-time or text?  Have you tried simply subtracting?  What do you get?

Comment: First apply `mm/dd/yy h:mm AM/PM` format to `Col D & E` then use this formula in  `Col F`  `=TEXT(E2-D2,"[h]:mm")`, **using your values with OP you get `4:30` (4 Hrs & 30 Mnts).**

Comment: Always enter Time in `24 Hrs format` like for `5:45 PM` should `17:45`.

Comment: @ScottCraner The total hours are already calculated in column C. fixer1234 and Rajesh the Date/Time format comes in as "Custom m/d/yyyy h:mm"  What I'm trying to get to here is a way to compare a payroll summary that has the employees date/hours worked (on the day that they clocked-in) vs tickets of work done.  I need to get those tickets that the driver did after midnight back on the previous day so it will show as accumulated hours on the date of clock-in.

Comment: After some experimenting, I think I found a way to get my result.  I will share it with the group in case someone else falls into this loop.    First thing I done was insert a column and copy the column D) Start Time data into the new column.  I then changed the format of the new column to General (this broke the time and date down to decimal serial numbers)  I then made another new column and came up with the following formula =[@Column2]-0.229 what this does is takes away 5 hours and 29 minutes (0.229) from the start time which in turn throws the ticket back to the original clock-in date.

Comment: @easttexas937 you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list.  ( :

Comment: + I just get to know that you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) here.. nice..

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, I think I found a way to get my result. I will share it in case someone else falls into this loop.

The first thing I did was to insert a new column and copy the column `D` Start Time data into it.

Then I changed the format of the new column to General (this broke the time and date down to decimal serial numbers).

Finally, I made another new column and came up with this formula `=[@Column2]-0.229`. What this does is takes away 5 hours and 29 minutes (0.229) from the start time which in turn throws the ticket back to the original clock-in date.

This can also be simplified by just adding a new column and use a formula subtracting 0.229 from the date/time in column `D`.